# Background from patch in CSS

Tags: html, css

How to make background in CSS like this?
https://www.behance.net/gallery/58402953/Maestro-App-Landing-Page-Design

Comment: Simply use image.

Comment: Be more specific. You want a background like that or a page like that? If you want a background use "background-image: url("URL HERE");"

Comment: If you try to design the background through CSS then first you try yourself. if you face any problem then come up with your code.

Comment: I dont want use image. I want use linear gradient, patch etc

Answer (score 0):

Use this css property `background-image: url()` read this article to understand better: [CSS background-image](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).